# window.location.href not redirecting in IE 8

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, internet-explorer-8, jsonresult

I am updating a textbox inside grid in MVC 4. The value is updated but the page is not refreshed and redirected to the specified actionresult in IE 8.
**Controller code**

```
public JsonResult UpdateCart(int Quantity, int ProductID)
{
  if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"] != null)
   {             
    objcartresponse.ProductID           = ProductID;
    objcartresponse.Quantity            = Quantity;                
    objcart.UpdateCart(objcartresponse);
    return Json(new
                {
                    redirectUrl = Url.Action("ShoppingCart", "Cart"),
                    isRedirect = true
                });
     }
     else
     {
     return Json(new
                {
                    redirectUrl = Url.Action("Login", "Account"),
                    isRedirect = true
                });
     }
 }
```

**jQuery code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(function () {
       $('.edit-mode').hide();
       $('.edit-user, .cancel-user').on('click', function () {
       var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
        tr.find('.edit-mode,.display-mode').toggle();
 });    
  $('.save-TZ').on('click', function () {
       var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
       var id = $(this).attr('id');
       var qty = tr.find("#Quantity").val();
       tr.find('.edit-mode,.display-mode').toggle();
       var Wishlist = { "Quantity": qty,  "ProductID": id    };
       $.ajax({
            url: '/Cart/UpdateCart/',
            data: JSON.stringify(Wishlist),
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (json) {
                     if (json.isRedirect) {
                     window.location.href = json.redirectUrl;
            }
               }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

I tried changing the **window.location.href** in jquery to **window.location**. But its also not working in IE 8. But in other browsers like chrome & FF its working fine. Any suggestions to make the code to work in IE 8 ?? Is there any mistake in the code.

Comment: Try `window.location= json.redirectUrl;`

Comment: Yes tried. But its also not working.

Comment: try window.location.replace ("/test")

Comment: @Anirudh : I dont want to hardcode the url value. Why is this happening only in IE 8.

Comment: @kk1076 Can you check one more thing, I means maybe one url is start with www. and another one is not start with www.

Comment: @Anirudh : As mentioned in my controller, the redirect url gets any of the two values. 1. Cart/ShoppingCart 2. Login/Account